# How to solve $tx''-x'-4t^3x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $$tx''-x'-4t^3x=0$$

I came across this example and it seems difficult to me. Any hints on how to start solving it?

Comment: Does *Fröbenius* ring a bell to you?

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Use $\ds{\tau \equiv t^{2}\ \imp\ t = \tau^{1/2}}$:

> \begin{align}
> \totald{}{t}&=\totald{\tau}{t}\,\totald{}{\tau}=2t\,\totald{}{\tau}
> =2\tau^{1/2}\,\totald{}{\tau}
> \\[5mm]
> \totald[2]{}{t}&=4\tau^{1/2}\,\totald{}{\tau}\pars{\tau^{1/2}\,\totald{}{\tau}}
> =4\tau^{1/2}\pars{\half\,\tau^{-1/2}\,\totald{}{\tau}
> +\tau^{1/2}\,\totald[2]{}{\tau}}
> =2\,\totald{}{\tau} + 4\tau\,\totald[2]{}{\tau}
> \end{align}

The equation becomes
\begin{align}
0&=\tau^{1/2}\pars{2\,\totald{}{\tau} + 4\tau\,\totald[2]{}{\tau}}x
-\pars{2\tau^{1/2}\,\totald{}{\tau}}x - 4\tau^{3/2}x
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> 0&=4\tau^{3/2}\,\totald[2]{x}{\tau} - 4\tau^{3/2}x
> \quad\imp\color{#66f}{\large\quad\totald[2]{x}{\tau} - x = 0}
> \end{align}

Solutions are linear combinations of $\ds{\expo{\pm\tau}}$. Namely,
linear combinations of $\ds{\expo{\pm t^{2}}}$.

Comment: But how do I know what substitution should I use. Is there some kind of general rule about substitutions?

Comment: Or maybe its some kind of intuition that comes after solving hundreds of diff. equations?

Comment: @Lugi I guess there is no rule about. Your equation can be written as $0={{\rm d}^{2}x \over \dd t^{2}} - {1 \over t}\,{{\rm d}x \over \dd t} + t^{2}x={{\rm d}^{2}x \over \dd t^{2}} - 2\,{{\rm d}x \over \dd\left(t^{2}\right)} + t^{2}x$. Now, you see that $t^{2}$ appear in two places. We can suspect that it has something to do with an equation reduction. So, we try that to see if the first term does something that simplifies the equation. It's a kind of a guess.

Comment: @Lugi There are some nice methods in [Applications of Lie Groups to Difference Equations (Differential and Integral Equations and Their Applications)](http://www.amazon.com/Applications-Difference-Equations-Differential-Integral/dp/1420083090/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1408744808&sr=8-1&keywords=Dorodnitsyn) .

Answer (score 3):

Let $x(t) = y(t^2)$. Then, $x'(t) = 2ty'(t^2)$ and $x''(t) = 2y'(t^2)+4t^2y''(t^2)$.

$tx''(t)-x'(t)-4t^3x(t) = 0$

$t[2y'(t^2)+4t^2y''(t^2)]-[2ty'(t^2)]-4t^3[y(t^2)] = 0$

$4t^3[y''(t^2)-y(t^2)] = 0$

$y'' - y = 0$

Can you solve this ODE?